# Avoid passing down props using Styled Components and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, styled-components

I have the following Styled Component in a React app that works as expected:

```
const BaseButton = styled(Button)<{ borderColor: string }>`
  border-color: ${({ borderColor }): string => borderColor};
`;
```

However it generates this warning message in the console:

> React does not recognize the `borderColor` prop on a DOM element. If
>   you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute,
>   spell it as lowercase `bordercolor` instead. If you accidentally
>   passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

In order to avoid this, I've tried to implement the solution proposed in the [documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props)

Documentation example:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Header, { Props as HeaderProps } from './Header'

const Title =
  styled <
  { isActive: boolean } >
  (({ isActive, ...rest }) => <Header {...rest} />)`
  color: ${props => (
  props.isActive ? props.theme.primaryColor : props.theme.secondaryColor
)}
`
```

My original code rewritten following the example:

```
const BaseButton = styled <
{ borderColor: string } >
(({ borderColor, ...rest }) => <Button {...rest} />)`
  border-color: ${({ borderColor }): string => borderColor};
`;
```

But I get the following error message:

> Parsing error: '>' expected

The error refers to `<Button {rest...} />`

This is my `.babelrc` config in case something is amiss:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/typescript", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing code was already right, but react gave you two options :

1) use lower case than snake-case

2) remove the attribute from DOM (you took this approach)

From the code I can see that you need the prop `borderColor`, but in the custom styling, you separated the props

`({borderColor,... rest}) => <Button {...rest} />`

You removed the border Color prop but you try to access in styled props the next line.

Instead try to rename the prop to `bordercolor` if you want warning to go away or just ignore warning.

Comment: First option: it indeed fixes the warning, but as described in the warning message, it passes to the underlying `button` HTML tag the `bordercolor` prop, which I want to avoid.

Second option: I've updated the initial post with the documentation example code. As you can see, after destructuring, the `isActive` prop is still available for use in the next line.

Comment: I've ended up following the first option, the only drawback was that it displays the bordercolor prop in the HTML tag.

Comment: it will throw error you spread the props, if eslint + airbnb is configured.

Answer (score 18):

## [Use Transient props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props)

> TL;DR just prefix your attriibute with `$` sign. example `$borderColor`, `$black`, `$any`, `$attribute`.

If you want to prevent props meant to be consumed by styled components from being passed to the underlying React node or rendered to the DOM element, you can prefix the prop name with a dollar sign ($), turning it into a transient prop.

```js
// typescript example
const BaseButton = styled(Button)<{ $borderColor: string }>`
    border-color: ${({ $borderColor }): string => $borderColor};
`;
```

```js
// js
const BaseButton = styled(Button)`
    border-color: ${({$borderColor}) => $borderColor}
`;
```

```
// usage
<BaseButton $borderColor="red">Button</BaseButton>
```

### 2nd method

[Checkout shouldForwardProp](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#shouldforwardprop)

```
const Comp = styled('div').withConfig({
  shouldForwardProp: (prop, defaultValidatorFn) =>
      !['hidden'].includes(prop)
      && defaultValidatorFn(prop),
}).attrs({ className: 'foo' })`
  color: red;
  &.foo {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
`;

render(
  <Comp hidden draggable="true">
    Drag Me!
  </Comp>
);
```

Comment: Awesome to know about Transient props!! Thanks again Ankit, this should actually be marked as the correct answer as it's more related to styled-components rather than react itself...

Comment: This sucks. I already have the interfaces. How do I map them for the transient prop pattern?

Comment: @rfc1484 This should be the accepted answer. Method 2 was is what I use. `styled('div')` is what I was missing for components that use `styled.div` and the like.